# Supported php operand types?

Tags: php

I'm getting the following `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types` when I calculate a percentage using php operand, this is the code I'm using

```
       <p>
          <?php
             $baseprice = get_field_object('base_price');
             $basediscount = get_field_object('discount_applied'); 
          ?>
          Total price: 
           <?php 
             $division = $baseprice / $basediscount;
             $res = round($division * 100);
             echo $res; 
           ?>
       </p>
```

[This is the link I am following for the code](http://www.phpbook.net/how-to-calculate-a-percentage-with-php.html)

Comment: Once again - your code works fine and your error must be elsewhere. What line does the error happen on? What is the full error? [**Demo for working code here**](http://codepad.org/kTwfzsiM). **EDIT**: If [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:F2_lPwpSMcAJ:www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field_object/&hl=en&gl=dk&strip=1) is the `get_field_object` method you use, then it'll return an object and you need to make sure that `$division = $baseprice->value / $basediscount->value`.

Comment: Check `$baseprice` and `$basediscount` data type. I am not sure it is integer or float;

Comment: this is the full code, and it says error on line 32: http://pastebin.com/WzNLf9Fa

Comment: mm ok $baseprice is €2,500.00 and $basediscount is 25.00

Comment: Why don't you just use `get_field('base_price')` and `get_field('discount_applied')` like earlier in your code?

Comment: perfect, you're right. Didn't have to use get_field_object but simply get_field. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code and simplify it It works. I've checked

```
     <?php
      $baseprice = 120.00;
      $basediscount = 10; //assuming it's 10%
      $discount = round($baseprice*$basediscount/100);
      $price_after_discount = $baseprice-$discount;
      //the other option to count price after discount with 1 line
      /*$price_after_discount = $baseprice-round($baseprice*$basediscount/100);*/ 
      echo "discount: $discount<br />";
      echo "price after discount $price_after_discount";
     ?>
```

With this code there are no errors and it counts discount very well Result for the code above is **discount 12 price after discount 108**

**Notice:**

You don't check `$basediscount` variable and if its 0 then it will be fatal error because you cannot divide by 0

Comment: where are you defining $res?

Comment: you meant $price_after_discount = $baseprice-$discount;

Comment: Yes you're right, I've changed $res to $discount to make it more readable and I forgot to change it in equatation.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have forgotten your parenthesises to specify the parameters in the `round` function. You probably meant

```
$res = round($division * 100);
```

and not

```
$res = round$division * 100;
```

(which would make PHP think that you were trying to use `$` as an operand, as opposed to the usual `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `&`, `%`, `|` etc.)

Comment: @rob.m Can you update the OP with your new **full** code and the line on which the error happens? **Edit**: [As it should, it works completely fine for me. Your error must be elsewhere](http://codepad.org/CM5lO8pg).

Answer (score 1):

Please correct your code:-

```
 $res = round($division * 100);
```

see manual how round work : http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Check `$baseprice` and `$basediscount` data type. I am not sure it is integer or float.

I have generate one case for you if `$baseprice` or `basediscount` array than you will get this error. see here

http://codepad.org/BjxgN2lY

If it is int or float than it will surely work for you :-  as in below demo.

http://codepad.org/JC9QxMio

Answer (score 0):

```
    $res = round($division * 100);
```

before do this operation, do check `if($division > 0 )`
ie)

```
if($division > 0 )
 {
   $res = round($division * 100);
    echo $res;
  }
```